# Selecting elements using index relationship - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, indexing, vectorization

Can elements of a vector/matrix/tensor be selected using index relationships in MATLAB?

To clarify my question, I'll explain my problem.
I have a three-dimensional zero tensor `D(m,n,p)`.
I now need to set the elements to `1` for which it holds that `m == L-n+p+1`.
(`L` is just a constant in this.)

Is there a way to do this in MATLAB without resorting to nested for-loops?

Thanks!

Comment: Would the solution provided here work for you?

Comment: Yes it works perfectly, accepted as answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach # 1**

This might easy and straight-forward for people to follow if not as efficient as the other two approaches -

```
[M,N,P] = ndgrid(1:m,1:n,1:p) %// create all indices using m, n, p
D(M == L-N+P+1) = 1 %// perform m == L-n+p+1 to get a logical array which you 
                  %// can use to index into D and set the expected elements to 1
```

**Approach # 2**

```
RHS = bsxfun(@minus,1:p,[1:n]')+1+L; %//'# calculate `L-n+p+1`
D(bsxfun(@eq,[1:m]',permute(RHS,[3 1 2])))=1 %//'# perform equality `m == L-n+p+1`
```

**Approach # 3**

`Permuting` earlier could be beneficial from performance point of view, so you can modify approach #2 on that -

```
RHS = bsxfun(@minus,permute(1:p,[1 3 2]),[1:n]) + L + 1
D(bsxfun(@eq,[1:m]',RHS))=1
```